# Wpf application slow when connected to internet

Tags: wpf, performance, monitoring, wireshark

We recently developed a wpf application for a client. Everything works fine but when the client connects to the internet the wpf application is slow during startup,changing from one tab to another and also when opening reports.I tried to check using wireshark but there was no direct request to internet from the Wpf application.I am kind of stuck in this situation.Please help me out guys.

P.S:It is not happening in our network but it happens only in our clients network can it be cause by the internet proxy that the client uses.

Comment: Are you sure the computer does not have  a virus?

Comment: The client has Eset Endpoint anti virus,so I assume it is virus free. Sorry but i dont have access to clients system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the application was trying to get some certificates from Microsoft and that was causing the delay. Once we added an exception for this certificate the performance issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If the wpf application is visually slow that suggests that network related work is being done on the GUI thread. Isolate all non GUI operations into background threads and tasks to provide a smooth user experience when using the GUI.

Comment: But when the application is not connected to internet the application is fast. So i dont know if this will help.

Comment: Your comment reinforces the suggestion that your network code is the issue.

Comment: @Prashanth I take what you said is true. When not connected to the internet, there are *no network operations* hence the GUI is not slow. But when connected the GUI slows down. Something *when connected* is slowing the GUI down.

Comment: So please suggest me ways to find these GUI. I am completely new with this,so I have no idea what you are telling?

Comment: @Prashanth How is the data loaded to the screen could be one. Where are the calls to the network done? Are they don't when the user presses a button or logs on to the system? Anywhere there is code which does **any** *non gui* work on a gui thread is the culprit.

Comment: @Prashanth For an example of putting work into a background thread see my article [C# WPF: Threading, Control Updating, Status Bar and Cancel Operations Example All In One](http://omegacoder.com/?p=642)